# Vue filters only work on first pagination page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, filtering, vuetify.js

I implemented filtering and pagination using Vue/Vuetify. The filtering works fine on the first pagination page, however, it doesn't work on any of the other pages of my table. I wasn't able to find the answer from similarly asked questions here. I'm looking for help to fix this issue.

Basically, the current behavior is filtering only works on the first page of the data table. If you click next on my pagination feature to load in the next cut of data, the data loads onto the table properly, but my filtering features no longer work. So let's say I filter by industryChoice, for example, engineering, the filtering brings up all the engineering jobs properly on the first pagination page, however, If I were to filter for industryChoice on any of the other pagination pages, the filtering doesn't work. It only works on the first cut of pagination data. I'm just wondering how I can fix this issue

```
firestore() {
      return {
        jobs: db.collection('jobs').orderBy('createdAt')
      }
    },
```

```
    methods: {
      next() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.totalPages) {
          this.currentPage++
        }
      },
      prev() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1) {
          this.currentPage--
        }
      }
    },
```

```
    computed: {

      // ************************************
      // Pagination
      // ************************************

      allJobs() {
        return Object.keys(this.searchJobs).map(pid => this.searchJobs[pid])
      },
      filteredJobs() {
        return this.allJobs.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.postsPerPage, this.currentPage * this.postsPerPage)
      },
      totalPages() {
        return Math.ceil(this.allJobs.length / this.postsPerPage)
      },

      // ************************************
      // Filters
     // ************************************

      searchJobs() {
        // ************************************
        // ************ search ****************
        // ************************************
        if (this.search != '') {
          return this.jobs.filter(a_job => {
            return a_job.jobTitle.match(this.search.toUpperCase().trim())
          })
        }

        // ************************************
        // ********* industryChoice ***********
        // ************************************
        else if (this.industryChoice != '') {
          // levelChoice && rangeChoice
          if (this.levelChoice != '' && this.rangeChoice != '') {
            return this.jobs
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.industryType.match(this.industryChoice)
              })
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.levelChoice.match(this.levelChoice)
              })
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.salaryRangeChoice.match(this.rangeChoice)
              })
          }
          // levelChoice && !rangeChoice
          else if (this.levelChoice != '') {
            return this.jobs
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.industryType.match(this.industryChoice)
              })
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.levelChoice.match(this.levelChoice)
              })
            // !levelChoice && rangeChoice
          } else if (this.rangeChoice != '') {
            return this.jobs
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.industryType.match(this.industryChoice)
              })
              .filter(a_job => {
                return a_job.salaryRangeChoice.match(this.rangeChoice)
              })
          }
          // !levelChoice && !rangeChoice
          else {
            return this.jobs.filter(a_job => {
              return a_job.industryType.match(this.industryChoice)
            })
          }
        }
        // ************************************
        // ********** levelChoice *************
        // ************************************
        else if (this.levelChoice != '') {
          return this.jobs.filter(a_job => {
            return a_job.levelChoice.match(this.levelChoice)
          })
        }
        // ************************************
        // ********** rangeChoice *************
        // ************************************
        else if (this.rangeChoice != '') {
          return this.jobs.filter(a_job => {
            return a_job.salaryRangeChoice.match(this.rangeChoice)
          })
        }
        // ************************************
        // ************************************
        // ************************************
        else {
          return this.jobs.filter(a_job => {
            return a_job.jobTitle.match(this.filterIndustry)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here are the Filters in the template

```
<template>

  <div class="jobboard">
    <!-- ****************************************************** -->
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <!-- ***************** Filters **************************** -->
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <v-flex xs12 sm2 md2 fixed>
        <v-card flat app
                class="lightgrey accent-5"
                wrap>
          <v-layout column fill-height class="pb-5">
            <v-flex fixed class="mt-5">

              <!-- ***** SEARCH *****-->
              <div class="pb-5">
                <v-icon medium left>search</v-icon>
                <input type="text"
                       v-model="search"
                       placeholder="Search Job Titles">
              </div>

              <!-- ***** Industry List *****-->
              <v-select v-model="industryChoice"
                        :items="industryType"
                        menu-props="auto"
                        label="Industry Type"
                        hide-details
                        prepend-icon="domain"
                        single-link
                        class="pb-5"></v-select>

              <!-- ***** Skill Level List *****-->
              <v-select v-model="levelChoice"
                        :items="jobLevel"
                        menu-props="auto"
                        label="Level"
                        hide-details
                        prepend-icon="supervisor_account"
                        single-link
                        class="pb-5"></v-select>

              <!-- ***** Salary List *****-->
              <v-select v-model="rangeChoice"
                        :items="salaryLevel"
                        menu-props="auto"
                        label="Salary Range"
                        hide-details
                        prepend-icon="attach_money"
                        single-link
                        class="pb-5"></v-select>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
```

and my table in the template

```
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <!-- ********************  Table ************************** -->
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <v-flex xs6 sm8 md8>
        <div v-if="$apollo.loading">Loading...</div>
        <div v-else>

          <v-card wrap app flat v-for="(a_job, idx) in filteredJobs" :key="idx">

            <div class="cardOne">
              <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">

                <v-card :elevation="hover ? 12 : 2" class="mx-auto">

                  <v-layout column wrap :class="`project ${a_job.jobTitle}`">

                    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 class="pl-2">

                      <v-tooltip right eager>
                        <v-btn flat small
                               slot="activator"
                               outlined
                               :to="{name:'jobDetails', params:{docid:a_job.id}}"
                               class="pl-2 pt-2">
                          <div class="positionTitle">{{ a_job.jobTitle }}</div>
                        </v-btn>
                        <v-icon small color="white">keyboard_backspace</v-icon>
                        <span>View Details</span>
                      </v-tooltip>

                      <div class="companyName pl-3 pb-1">{{ a_job.coName }}</div>
                      <h3 class="locationSlot pl-3 pb-1">{{ a_job.levelChoice }} | {{ a_job.jobLocation }}</h3>

                    </v-flex>

                    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 class="">

                      <div class="text-center pb-2 pl-2">
                        <v-btn small to="/applyforjob" class="applyButton applyBtn " dark>Apply</v-btn>
                      </div>

                    </v-flex>

                  </v-layout>
                </v-card>
              </v-hover>
            </div>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
          </v-card>
        </div>
      </v-flex>

      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <v-flex xs6 sm2 md2>

        <v-layout row class="pl-4">
          <v-img class=" pt-4 pl-3 ">
            <img src="../assets/testAd2.png">
          </v-img>
        </v-layout>

      </v-flex>
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->
      <!-- ******************** NEXT BTN ************************ -->
      <!-- ****************************************************** -->

      <v-flex xs4 sm4 md4>
        <div class="text-center pl-pt-4 pb-4">
          <v-btn @click="prev" class="applyButton applyBtn " dark>Prev</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click="next" class="applyButton applyBtn " dark>Next</v-btn>
        </div>
      </v-flex>



      <!-- ***************************************************** -->
      <!-- ******************** Footer 1 *********************** -->
      <!-- ***************************************************** -->
      <v-layout justify-center wrap class=" homeFoot">

        <v-flex xs12 sm12 md12 class="homeBottom pt-3">
          <div class="connectCard homeBottom pb-2">
            <div class="connectCard">
              <img class="text-lg-center px-1" src="../assets/facebookIcon1.png">
              <img class="text-lg-center px-1" src="../assets/linkedinCuteIcon1.png">
              <img class="text-lg-center px-1" src="../assets/twitterCuteIcon2.png">
              <img class="text-lg-center px-1" src="../assets/instagramCuteIcon1.png">
              <img class="text-lg-center  px-1" src="../assets/emailIconCute1.png">
              <p>Company Name, LLC. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-layout>

  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Could you please update the question to include a clear description of the current behaviour? Currently we just have that it *'doesn't work'*, which is a little vague.

Comment: Updated. Sorry.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not really clearer. Please try to write the description without using the words *'doesn't work'*. Instead describe what does happen. Do you mean that trying to apply a filter to page 2 doesn't change the results, as though the filter is being ignored?

Comment: The filter is being ignored on the second page and every page after that. The filters only work on the first page without any issues at all. I have a feeling maybe it has to do with page two of data being loaded in isn't updating in the filter methods.

Comment: Could you confirm that you aren't seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the browser console.